# How to Group Data between DateTime using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

My student class is

```
class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Admission{get; set;}
}
```

I want to group the data between datetime where Admission must between Today 7 am to next morning 7 am , for example :- 11/4/2014 7:0:0 and 11/5/2014 7:0:0 all data between these datetime's must be in a single group

Currently i am doing it like this

```
var groupByAdmsn = listOfStudent.
GroupBy(x => x.Admission < new DateTime(x.Admission.Year, x.Admission.Month, x.Admission.Day, 7, 0, 0).AddDays(1) &&
 x.Admission >= new DateTime(x.Admission.Year, x.Admission.Month, x.Admission.Day, 7, 0, 0))
.Select(x => x)
.ToList();
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an IEqualityComparer:

```
public class DateComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
    {
            public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
            {
                    return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
            }

            public int GetHashCode(DateTime dt)
            {
                    // Normalise unique hashcode to single group time [before 7am uses the previous day]
                    DateTime hashDt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
                    if (dt.Hour < 7)
                    {
                            hashDt = hashDt.AddDays(-1);
                    }
                    return hashDt.GetHashCode();
            }
    }
```

Example of call:

```
    var groupByAdmsn = listOfStudent.GroupBy(x => x.Admission , new DateComparer());
```

Comment: The solution given above need Little modification in the Equals method to work properly; Equals Method needs to return true every time, otherwise it group the data in new group even the hashcode is  of previous day. above code will not work for 11/5/2014 6:58:00 AM & 11/5/2014 6:21:00 AM. @ChrisC73 am i correct or there is some other reason that's why the code is not working.

Comment: You are absolutely correct: I have updated the answer to use the same logic as the hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

it's not working for you because you use the date in the Admission to create the new datetime to compare to, you have to use **today** datetime (or other specific date you want) to create the new datetime.
try this:

```
var groupByAdmsn = listOfStudent.
GroupBy(x => x.Admission < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 0, 0).AddDays(1) &&
 x.Admission >= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 0, 0))
.Select(x => x)
.ToList();
```